# Add MySql connection to a Configuration file

Tags: php, mysql, configuration-files

I wrote a php class which connects to a MySql DB, and then does an INSERT. I have done this, and it works. Now, i want to add the connection part of the code to a configuration file, where i could call it from here.

How could i do this in PHP ?

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "xxxxx") ;
mysql_select_db("mydb");
...
...// Insert to DB (which works)
?>
```

Comment: what have you tried? also new code should not use the mysql_* functions you should learn and use PDO or mysqli.

Comment: You mean something like include, include_once, require, or require_once?

Comment: @Tynarus I mean, to add the connection string in 1 file, and then access it where ever i want from another PHP file. (Something like a configuration file)

Comment: Use require_once to retrieve the configuration file? It will automatically run anything inside of the file you're fetching. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

Comment: Provided the configuration file is another PHP file, I should say. Apologies. HTML files work too, but then it would just display the HTML inside the file.

Comment: I think the answer could be seen [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079459/include-external-php-files

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand exactly but por put this parameters in a configuration file you do this
Configuration File

```
$config['hostname'] = 'yourserver';
$config['user'] = 'youruser';
$config['password'] = 'password';
```

and then call this in your class connection

```
mysql_connect($config['hostname'],$config['user'],$config['password']);
```

or more easy build a construct with the parameters of conexion, and look as this

```
function __construct($host,$user,$password,$database){
    mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) ;
    mysql_select_db($database);
}
```

Comment: +1 for the good answer. However, Y not encourage the use of MySQLi over MySQL_* ?

Comment: in mysql the way of conect is same mysqli_connect

Comment: a guide detail of advantages and disadvantages of pdo and mysqli [link]http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/[link] but PDO id a library general when you unknow the database server that use and mysqli is specific for mysql

Answer (score 1):

connect to a mysql database by using ph is very simple. you write the code in a ok way, although it is better to use MySQLi or PDO not MySQL function, because they may have some sql injection or other security problems.
give your file a name like config.php and add it to whenever you want to use mysql connection.
use require_once or include functions of php to use this.

hope it will help ..

Comment: So do i have to replace `mysql_` with `mysqli` everywhere in my code?

Comment: yes. you must do that.however it is not necessary, it is just because standard programmers are advised not to use mysql function.this is just for security reasons, although it works ok.

Comment: also you can use a if else condition in your config file. you can set in it , what server you are working on. if you working on localhost,then you can make a connection fir this ,else if you are on a live server then make another connection for this. then your one config file works fine on both station and you will not need to edit it.
if you find me helpful, please vote me:)

Answer (score 0):

As from a notice from PHP they wont be officially deprecating the mysql_* extension till at least PHP 5.5/6.0 so you have some time to rewrite your script before those function are completely gone or E_DEPRECATED errors start appearing. http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799

So use PDO or mysqli for new scripts:

**Connect with PDO**

```
<?php
try{
    $con = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test','root','password');
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}catch (Exception $e){
    die('Cannot connect to database. Details:'.$e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Right now, if the above code is in your config file then you can use `include('config.php')` and then
`$con` will contain your connection object.

As `$con` is not global scope you would need to pass it to your class via the construct.

```
<?php 
include('config.php');
class yourclass{

    function __construct(PDO $con){
        $this->db = $con;
    }

    function someMethod($valueA,$valueB){
        $sql = "INSERT
                INTO   TABLE
                       (
                              colA,
                              colB
                       )VALUES(
                              :colA,
                              :colB
                       )";
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);

        $query->bindParam(":colA", $valueA);
        $query->bindParam(":colB", $valueB);
        $query->execute();
    }
}
$aClass = new yourclass($con);
$aClass->someMethod('someValueforA','someValueforB');
?>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can write the connection coding in the constructor of the class,as :

```
function __construct($host,$user,$password,$dbname){

  mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) ;
  mysql_select_db($dbname);

}
```

Or you can create another class where connection is defined and then you can extend that class as per your need(inheritance)