# how doesn this variable called from another refrence

Tags: php

Any one knows how to use this php file called  dbconfig.php

```
<?php            
return array(
    // database info
    'db' => array(
        'database'  => 'mydb23',
        'username'  => 'user1',
        'password'  => 'pa123',
    )               
);
```

I need to know how to get variables (database and user name) on another php file, unfortunately this file used by a framework, so I can change it, I'm trying to use same file with external php file , not within framework.

like add it to my another index.php

```
include('dbconfig.php');



    <?php
    echo  array_values('db','database'); didn't work
    ?>
```

Comment: the include shoud be inside php tag's

Comment: What framework is it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [include external php files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079459/include-external-php-files)